# jQuery Ajax submit twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form and i implement the bootstrapValidator plugin, also i add my personal code to check on the email,it's just a test.
But when i submit the form, it submits twice.
I don't know why?

```
(function(){
    $("#defaultForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "testEmail.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {"email": $("#email").val()},
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    });
})();
```

Here is my php code :

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo $email;
```

I use this email to test : "amine@gmail.com" and the output is

> `amine@gmail.com amine@gmail.com`

Comment: What is shown will not cause that behavior by itself. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: provide html a well with it for this ques

Comment: Best guess 1) php is trying to convert json to a string or 2) your response actually contains the email listed twice (which would mean the issue is on the server-side)